# When key pressed if timer>500, do something

Tags: java

I'm working on a small project where I want to be able to call a method by pressing a key. I only want the method to be able to be called every 1/2 second. Is there a way I can set up a timer to keep track of how long since a key was pushed and then reset it after every time the method is called? Here's kinda the idea in pseudocode

```
public class Checker{
   public Checker(x){
      Timer t=new Timer(x);
      t.start();
      int i=1;
      while(i=1){
         if(Keypressed.K && t>500){
            //call method
         }
      t.restart();
      }
```

do you guys think this is the best way to go about it? And would it be possible for my program to do other things while this is active or would it just be stuck in the loop?

Answer (score 1):

On your key press code, have a `long` variable set to the last successful key press.

Each time the user presses the key, check if the last successful press was long enough ago to allow input through.

```
long lastPress = 0;
public void keyPress()
{
    if(lastPress + 500 > System.currentTimeMillis())
        return;
    //dostuff
    lastPress = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

This should be optimal, as you no longer need to worry about multithreading a check to see if enough time has passed, and instead just check on user input.

---

EDIT:

Proof of working:

```
public class Test
{
  private static long lastPress = 0;

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while(System.currentTimeMillis() - 4000 < start)
    {
      keyPress();
    }
  }

  public static void keyPress()
  {
    if(lastPress + 500 > System.currentTimeMillis())
      return;
    System.out.println("Successful press at " + System.currentTimeMillis());
    lastPress = System.currentTimeMillis();
  }
}
```

Ran in [compilejava.net](http://www.compilejava.net/), which is ran on Debian, JDK 1.8.0_60

Outputs:

```
Successful press at 1447291059524
Successful press at 1447291060024
Successful press at 1447291060524
Successful press at 1447291061024
Successful press at 1447291061524
Successful press at 1447291062024
Successful press at 1447291062524
Successful press at 1447291063024
Successful press at 1447291063524
```

Was going to delay it randomly with `Thread.sleep()`, but this gets the point across

Comment: This won't work.  You assign lastPress to 0 initially.  Not to mention that you scope the variable outside of the method body which is unnecessary and will give a beginner problems trying to run from a static context.

Comment: @MichaelQuatrani It needs to be accessible by each call to `keyPress()`, it is in the correct location to save it's state.  As for initializing `lastPress = 0`, it's so that the first call will work no matter when it's called.  Please re-evaluate the code I posted and rethink your comment.

Comment: It won't work the first time.  It would work on subsequent pushes but the first press would be an error.  Additionally, it can be scoped locally without any problems.  So your statement "it is in the correct location to save it's state" is erroneous.  The "state" of a java program is a complex beast. This would include the complete heap, the execution point of all threads, values of local variables ...

Comment: @MichaelQuatrani Do you need me to explain how this program works step by step?  I can either do that in chat for you or shall I put a step by step procedure of how it works into my answer?  If it doesn't work the first try, it will never work because it will always hit the `return;` statement

Comment: can you provide working code which includes your method and the original question?

Comment: @MichaelQuatrani I've mostly adapted it from the logic of other programs written in TorqueScript, I shall write up a small example with this and add it to the answer

Comment: You are correct.  Good job and thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `sleep` to achieve your goal here, however, executing methods like this is not recommended.

```
public class SleepMessages {
    public static void main(String args[])
        throws InterruptedException {
        String importantInfo[] = {
            "Mares eat oats",
            "Does eat oats",
            "Little lambs eat ivy",
            "A kid will eat ivy too"
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < importantInfo.length; i++) {
            //Pause for 4 seconds
            Thread.sleep(4000);
            //Print a message
            System.out.println(importantInfo[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

[oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html)

```
if(Keypressed.K){
            //call method
            Thread.sleep(500)
         }
```

Comment: While this is better than using a `while(true)` loop to delay the code, I don't think this is such a good practice for the desired effect

Comment: @phflack I agree, however, in all fairness, I did include that disclaimer in the beginning of the answer.

Comment: I think we should be answering the overarching goal instead of encouraging a bad style/habit, but at least the lesser goal was answered